# Game of Life, method doesnt work

Tags: java, for-loop, methods, conways-game-of-life

I'm not sure if I am turning mad but this is what my problem is:

I programm Game of Life and have a "countalive" method which counts how many surrounding fields are alive.

```
    public int countalive(Board board, int yaxis, int xaxis) { //defekt

    int living = board.getfields()[yaxis - 1][xaxis - 1] + board.getfields()[yaxis - 1][xaxis] + board.getfields()[yaxis - 1][xaxis + 1] + 
            board.getfields()[yaxis][xaxis - 1] + board.getfields()[yaxis][xaxis + 1] + board.getfields()[yaxis + 1][xaxis - 1] +
            board.getfields()[yaxis + 1][xaxis] + board.getfields()[yaxis + 1][xaxis + 1];
    return living;
}
```

This method seems to work perfectly fine. But when i do this

```
 public Board evolve(Board board) {
    Board tmpboard = board;
    System.out.println(countalive(board, 1, 3));  //I test with this. SHOULD AND IS 2!!
    int aliveneighbours = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < board.getfields().length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < board.getfields()[i].length - 1; j++) {
            System.out.print("i = " +i);
            System.out.print("j = " +j +" ");
            aliveneighbours = countalive(board, i, j);
            System.out.println(aliveneighbours);

            if (aliveneighbours == 3) {
                tmpboard.getfields()[i][j] = 1;
            } else if (aliveneighbours < 2 || aliveneighbours > 3) {
                tmpboard.getfields()[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
    return tmpboard;
}
```

I get this in the console:

```
2
i = 1j = 1 1
i = 1j = 2 1
i = 1j = 3 1
i = 1j = 4 1
i = 1j = 5 0
...
```

even though i = 1 and j =3 should be 2 and not 1. As you see the the method countalive(board, 1, 3) works but in the for loop it gives me a different result. Can you find my error?

Comment: I think we might need to see your testing `Board` state as well. However it's worth mentioning that you are accessing `(Y, X)` which struck me as strange (convention is `(X, Y)`, no?)

Comment: Does this line `Board tmpboard = board;` give you a *copy* of the current board? Your result *might* be explained if somehow `tmpboard == board` -- that is, you are changing `board` by changing `tmpboard`. If Java's rules are not clear on this (they are not to me), you could test by changing something in `tmpboard` and then examining `board` itself.

Comment: @Jongware Yes board tmpboard = board gives me a copy. I printed the board and the tmpboard after every iteration and you seem to be right. The board also changes even though it shouldn't

Comment: It's because Java is taking the line `tmpboard = board` *literally*! So indeed, since they are "equal", changing one also changes the other. Create a new empty board and copy the individual cells instead.

Comment: What a mess, nightmare to debug

Comment: Do you leave out the border cells on purpose?

Comment: @MarkHomer yeah im a noob :( Fildor yes, they are the frame of the field

Comment: @Jongware exactly what was wrong with mine, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are changing the aliveness of cells during the iteration. What you need to do is to have a separate array for the next generation and update that based on this generation, then swap them once you have completely looked at the current generation.

Comment: sadly no, I change the alivnes in the tmpboard, but look after the neighbours in the non changed board. I never change board, i only change the copy (tmpboard) of it and return the copy EDIT: ok seems like you are right. I dont know why, but the original also changes

Comment: an array is an object in java. if you have the pointer `board` to that array and create `tmpBoard`, they both point to the same array. thats why you need a real copy.